# Reporting multinomial regression results to a non-stat audience

Tags: reporting, multinomial-logit, communication

I would appreciate a little bit of advice on reporting. I've run a set of multinomial regression models, done my model testing, all that good stuff. Now I am waffling on how I want to report the results. My audience will not follow along with odds ratios, so I am using the sigmoid function to report in probabilities. Even probability will be a challenge but less so than odds.

Normally I would just apply it to the log odds estimate itself, and explain "when holding all others constant, the effect of Variable X on probability of event 1 is ..." however even that might be too complicated for what I need.

For example, for event 1 I have the following results for my coefficient estimates

**Log odds estimates**

- Intercept: -3.291
- Variable A (binary): -0.017
- Variable B (binary): 0.434
- Variable C (binary): 0.641

With the sigmoid function applied to just the estimates:

**Effect on p(Y=1)**

- Intercept: 0.036
- Variable A (binary): 0.496
- Variable B (binary): 0.607
- Variable C (binary): 0.655

However my audience will not understand how the effects of the variables on the probability will be so high (even with explaining that it doesn't account for the rest of the effects or the intercept)

So I am thinking I'll include the effect of the intercept (that is, when exponentiating the logit, I'll include Intercept + Variable). Then the explanation could be the effect of the variable while holding everything else constant, and I don't have to explain about the intercept?

**Effect on p(Y=1)**

- Intercept + Variable A (binary): 0.035
- Intercept + Variable B (binary): 0.054
- Intercept + Variable C (binary): 0.066

The purpose of this analysis is not for predictive purposes but to look at the effect each Variable has on the probability of outcome and it's not intended to be particularly in-depth, so I think this might be the simplest way to go about it. Does this sound like complete nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

When I present to a non-statistical audience, I like to use examples. You don't say what you are studying but I would say something like

> So, the model predicts that a White man who is over 65 years old would
> be 3 times more likely to be a Republican.

Only, of course, using examples relevant to your case.

Answer (score 0):

For binary variables, one thing you could do is look at the average effect by flipping each variable across all observations and calculating the average change in probability. For continuous variables, you can do the same with a 1 std dev change.
You can also convert the probability effects to something more meaningful, like revenue